# How to create a SP doc library view to get a drop down for all metadata columns

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-on-prem, view

I have a requirement to see it would be possible to create a document library view that loads as below.
[image]

One of the users was able to see when he Filter=1 at the end of the URL manually in browser, is it possible to setup a view like this? I am working sp on prem 2019.